# Object defineProperty setter for properties

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using NodeJS, I'm trying to keep track of changes to Model attributes regardless of what type they may be. Using `Object.defineProperty` setters usually work great, but for Objects and arrays, if a property of the object is set I'm unable to track changes that are made.

I realize that the setter isn't the object itself, but is there a way I can get it to function as though it is?

For example, can I get the below code to trigger the setter when a "property" of the setter is set?

```
var model = {};
model.attributes = {};

Object.defineProperty(model, 'options', {
    get: function() {
        return this.attributes.options;
    },
    set: function(value) {
        console.log('changed options from:', this.attributes.options, 'to', value);
        this.attributes.options = value;
    }
});

model.options = {};
model.options = { a: 50 }; // triggers setter
model.options.b = 60;      // doesn't trigger setter, how can I get it to do so?
```

Comment: in short: no, you can't subscribe unknown properties, including sub-properties with ODP. look into Object.observe()-type stuff

Comment: @dandavis Ah, bummer. It looks like Node only supports Object.observe in the latest (ie. non-stable) versions, so I may just explore some other approaches. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The Harmony proxy might help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using an ES6 transpiler that supports proxies, you can solve the problem like the so:

```
var handler = {
  defineProperty (target, key, descriptor) {
    console.log('changed options from:', target[key], 'to', descriptor.value);
    if(typeof descriptor.value === 'object'){
        descriptor.value = new Proxy(descriptor.value,handler);
    }
    Object.defineProperty(target, key, descriptor);
    return true;
  }
}

var target = {}
var proxy = new Proxy(target, handler)

proxy.foo = 'bar2'        // changed from undefined to bar2
proxy.foo = 'bar'         // changed from bar2 to bar
proxy.options = { a: 50 } // changed from undefined to Object { a: 50 }
proxy.options.a = 15      // changed from 50 to 15
proxy.options.b = 60      // changed from undefined to 60
```

Inspired by [this](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-proxy-traps-in-depth) article

Comment: Proxies might be able to do it, but this implementation doesn't fix the core problem: detecting when nested properties are defined/set. You can see what I mean here: https://jsfiddle.net/rosszurowski/ef0h67qq/1/

Maybe this can be solved via the `set` property of the handler?

Comment: Yeah my initial attempt was a bit sloppy, check out my edited version. Depending on exactly how you want to use it, you might want to extend it a bit more

Comment: Haha, that's a sneaky way of doing it, but it works. Thanks!